# Double jsvc process

Tags: java, tomcat, jsvc

I started tomcat through jsvc as daemon. But after jsvc started, I see double jsvc process.
Process had started by daemon.sh with option start:

```
start   )
"$JSVC" $JSVC_OPTS \
-java-home "$JAVA_HOME" \
-java-home /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.7.0_11 \
-user $TOMCAT_USER \
-pidfile "$CATALINA_PID" \
-wait 10 \
-outfile "$CATALINA_OUT" \
-errfile "&1" \
-classpath "$CLASSPATH" \
"$LOGGING_CONFIG" $JAVA_OPTS $CATALINA_OPTS \
-Djava.endorsed.dirs="$JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS" \
-Dcatalina.base="$CATALINA_BASE" \
-Dcatalina.home="$CATALINA_HOME" \
-Djava.io.tmpdir="$CATALINA_TMP" \
$CATALINA_MAIN
exit $?
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your question is: Why do I get two processes? This could be because jsvc starts a main daemon process and a child process for the actual work.